# Proper resource names of a REST API

Tags: api, rest

Let's say we are making an invoice API. What is a more appropriate resource?

`GET`

- paid_invoices
- due_invoices
- all_invoices

or

`GET`

- invoices/all
- invoices/due
- invoices/paid

---

Additional question: If your API allows marking invoices as paid what's the proper resource?

`PUT` `//where 3 is the id`

- invoices/3

or

`PUT`

- pay_invoice/3

Comment: I was taught that having a verb in a REST uri was a big mistake hence use invoices/3 rather than pay_invoice/3. Similarly, the second set of GET operations ( invoices/all , etc) seems more elegant to me.

Comment: Alphabetic will predominate when it comes to order. This helps a lot on projects involving several programmers. But I guess it really depends on the approach and how well documented it'll be. I'd definetely go with the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:

- `GET /invoices` returns **all** invoices;
- A filter can return either **paid** or **due** invoices: `GET /invoices?state=paid` where `state` can be `paid` or `due`.

To mark an invoice as paid, you can either set the corresponding state to your resource, and then you just have to update (replace actually) it using `PUT /invoices/<id>`.

Alternatively, you can patch your resource: `PATCH /invoices/<id>`. This method requires a diff like `state=paid` for example.

It's just a matter of what you want to send to your API (a complete resource, or just the change to apply).

A non-REST solution could be to perform a `PATCH` request to `/invoices/<id>/paid`. It's not pure REST but it's ok.